# firefox NotConnectedException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, clojure, ubuntu-14.04

I have following configuration

java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-internal-b27)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

ubuntu 14.04

[clj-webdriver](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver)

and i am running following test

```
  (ns selenium-web.core-test
    (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
              [selenium-web.core :refer :all]
              [clj-webdriver.taxi :refer :all]))

  (deftest run-common-tets
    (set-driver! {:browser :firefox})
    (to "https://github.com")
    (click "a[href*='login']")
    (input-text "#login_field" "piyush")
    (-> "#password" (input-text "1") submit)
    (is (= "Incorrect username or password." (text ".flash")))
    (quit) )
```

and getting following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
{"langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1427084855000,"mt":1426961704000},"langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000}},"app-system-share":{"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1397697896000,"mt":1397665356000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1414992900000,"mt":1407283796000},"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1421386237000,"mt":1420839872000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1397697896000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1427189374023   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org
1427189374024   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1427189374024   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org
1427189374025   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/tmp/anonymous8984618018842301384webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.39.0","st":1427189365000,"mt":1427189365000}},"app-global":{"langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1427084855000,"mt":1426961704000},"langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000}},"app-system-share":{"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1397697896000,"mt":1397665356000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1414992900000,"mt":1407283796000},"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1421386237000,"mt":1420839872000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1397697896000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1427189374028   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1427189374033   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1427189374034   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1427189374035   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1427189374036   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1427189374038   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1427189374039   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1427189376827   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:195)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:313)
    at clj_webdriver.core$new_webdriver_STAR_.invoke(core.clj:188)
    at clj_webdriver.core$new_driver.invoke(core.clj:202)
    at clj_webdriver.taxi$set_driver_STAR_.invoke(taxi.clj:26)
    at clj_webdriver.taxi$set_driver_BANG_.invoke(taxi.clj:59)
    at selenium_web.core_test$fn__3756.invoke(core_test.clj:9)
    at clojure.test$test_var$fn__7187.invoke(test.clj:704)
    at clojure.test$test_var.invoke(test.clj:704)
    at clojure.test$test_vars$fn__7209$fn__7214.invoke(test.clj:722)
    at clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke(test.clj:674)
    at clojure.test$test_vars$fn__7209.invoke(test.clj:722)
    at clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke(test.clj:674)
    at clojure.test$test_vars.invoke(test.clj:718)
    at clojure.test$test_all_vars.invoke(test.clj:728)
    at clojure.test$test_ns.invoke(test.clj:747)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__4245.invoke(core.clj:2559)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.Cons.next(Cons.java:39)
    at clojure.lang.RT.boundedLength(RT.java:1654)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:130)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.test$run_tests.doInvoke(test.clj:762)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at user$eval85$fn__140$fn__171.invoke(form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    at user$eval85$fn__140$fn__141.invoke(form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    at user$eval85$fn__140.invoke(form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    at user$eval85.invoke(form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)

lein test :only selenium-web.core-test/run-common-tets

ERROR in (run-common-tets) (NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
{"langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1427084855000,"mt":1426961704000},"langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000}},"app-system-share":{"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1397697896000,"mt":1397665356000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1414992900000,"mt":1407283796000},"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1421386237000,"mt":1420839872000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1397697896000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1427189374023   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org
1427189374024   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1427189374024   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org
1427189374025   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/tmp/anonymous8984618018842301384webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.39.0","st":1427189365000,"mt":1427189365000}},"app-global":{"langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1427084855000,"mt":1426961704000},"langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000}},"app-system-share":{"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1397697896000,"mt":1397665356000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1414992900000,"mt":1407283796000},"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1421386237000,"mt":1420839872000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1397697896000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1427189374028   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1427189374033   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1427189374034   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1427189374035   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1427189374036   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1427189374038   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1427189374039   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1427189376827   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'piyush', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-46-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_40-internal'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start (NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient (FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init> (RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:195)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:422)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:442)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:93)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember (Reflector.java:313)
    clj_webdriver.core$new_webdriver_STAR_.invoke (core.clj:188)
    clj_webdriver.core$new_driver.invoke (core.clj:202)
    clj_webdriver.taxi$set_driver_STAR_.invoke (taxi.clj:26)
    clj_webdriver.taxi$set_driver_BANG_.invoke (taxi.clj:59)
    selenium_web.core_test/fn (core_test.clj:9)
    clojure.test$test_var$fn__7187.invoke (test.clj:704)
    clojure.test$test_var.invoke (test.clj:704)
    clojure.test$test_vars$fn__7209$fn__7214.invoke (test.clj:722)
    clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke (test.clj:674)
    clojure.test$test_vars$fn__7209.invoke (test.clj:722)
    clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke (test.clj:674)
    clojure.test$test_vars.invoke (test.clj:718)
    clojure.test$test_all_vars.invoke (test.clj:728)
    clojure.test$test_ns.invoke (test.clj:747)
    clojure.core$map$fn__4245.invoke (core.clj:2559)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
    clojure.lang.Cons.next (Cons.java:39)
    clojure.lang.RT.boundedLength (RT.java:1654)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:130)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:626)
    clojure.test$run_tests.doInvoke (test.clj:762)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:624)
    user$eval85$fn__140$fn__171.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    user$eval85$fn__140$fn__141.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    user$eval85$fn__140.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    user$eval85.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6703)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6693)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7130)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile (Compiler.java:7086)
    clojure.main$load_script.invoke (main.clj:274)
    clojure.main$init_opt.invoke (main.clj:279)
    clojure.main$initialize.invoke (main.clj:307)
    clojure.main$null_opt.invoke (main.clj:342)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:420)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:421)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:383)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
{"langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1427084855000,"mt":1426961704000},"langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000}},"app-system-share":{"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1397697896000,"mt":1397665356000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1414992900000,"mt":1407283796000},"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1421386237000,"mt":1420839872000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1397697896000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1427189374023   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org
1427189374024   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1427189374024   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org
1427189374025   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/tmp/anonymous8984618018842301384webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.39.0","st":1427189365000,"mt":1427189365000}},"app-global":{"langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1427084855000,"mt":1426961704000},"langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"36.0.4","st":1426962281000}},"app-system-share":{"webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"3.0.2","st":1397697896000,"mt":1397665356000},"{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}","e":false,"v":"2014.08.06.beta","st":1414992900000,"mt":1407283796000},"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com","e":false,"v":"3.0","st":1421386237000,"mt":1420839872000}},"app-system-local":{"online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net":{"d":"/usr/lib/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/online-accounts@lists.launchpad.net","e":false,"v":"0.5","st":1397697896000,"mt":1390969548000}}}
1427189374028   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1427189374033   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1427189374034   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1427189374035   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1427189374036   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1427189374038   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1427189374039   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1427189376827   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start (NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient (FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init> (RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:195)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init> (FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:422)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:442)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:93)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember (Reflector.java:313)
    clj_webdriver.core$new_webdriver_STAR_.invoke (core.clj:188)
    clj_webdriver.core$new_driver.invoke (core.clj:202)
    clj_webdriver.taxi$set_driver_STAR_.invoke (taxi.clj:26)
    clj_webdriver.taxi$set_driver_BANG_.invoke (taxi.clj:59)
    selenium_web.core_test/fn (core_test.clj:9)
    clojure.test$test_var$fn__7187.invoke (test.clj:704)
    clojure.test$test_var.invoke (test.clj:704)
    clojure.test$test_vars$fn__7209$fn__7214.invoke (test.clj:722)
    clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke (test.clj:674)
    clojure.test$test_vars$fn__7209.invoke (test.clj:722)
    clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke (test.clj:674)
    clojure.test$test_vars.invoke (test.clj:718)
    clojure.test$test_all_vars.invoke (test.clj:728)
    clojure.test$test_ns.invoke (test.clj:747)
    clojure.core$map$fn__4245.invoke (core.clj:2559)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
    clojure.lang.Cons.next (Cons.java:39)
    clojure.lang.RT.boundedLength (RT.java:1654)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:130)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:626)
    clojure.test$run_tests.doInvoke (test.clj:762)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:624)
    user$eval85$fn__140$fn__171.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    user$eval85$fn__140$fn__141.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    user$eval85$fn__140.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    user$eval85.invoke (form-init6043962041489599905.clj:1)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6703)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6693)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7130)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile (Compiler.java:7086)
    clojure.main$load_script.invoke (main.clj:274)
    clojure.main$init_opt.invoke (main.clj:279)
    clojure.main$initialize.invoke (main.clj:307)
    clojure.main$null_opt.invoke (main.clj:342)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:420)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:421)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:383)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 1 errors.
Tests failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually has to do with the clj-webdriver not having a recent enough version of selenium included. Firefox updates have frequent breaking changes in webdriver connectivity that are only supported by the latest selenium versions.

Change the `clj-webdriver` dependency in your `project.clj` to exclude the included selenium, and add the dependencies of the [latest selenium version](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) (2.45.0 at time of posting).

```
[clj-webdriver "0.6.1" :exclusion [com.github.detro.ghostdriver/phantomjsdriver
                                   org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server
                                   org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
                                   org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver]]
[org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server "2.45.0"]
[org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java "2.45.0"]
[org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver "2.45.0"]
```

Comment: ya..thankx man. I updated dependency and it's working now...!!

and thanks for early response.